# Борьба с ленивым chrome

Tags: анимация, animate, javascript, css

Есть у меня есть картинка с таким css:

```
top:7%;
left:20%;
width:60%;
position:absolute;
border-radius:50px;
```

Есть код:

```
function pause(ms)
{
var date = new Date();
var curDate = null;
do { curDate = new Date(); }
while(curDate-date < ms);
}
function pulse(id) {
document.getElementById(id).style.top = '3%';
document.getElementById(id).style.left = '16%';
document.getElementById(id).style.width = '68%';
pause(500);
document.getElementById(id).style.top = '9%';
document.getElementById(id).style.left = '22%';
document.getElementById(id).style.width = '56%';
pause(500);
document.getElementById(id).style.top = '7%';
document.getElementById(id).style.left = '20%';
document.getElementById(id).style.width = '60%';

}
```

Так вот, я запустил его. С картинкой ничего не изменилось. Мне кажется, что это из-за того, что хром сначала выполнил действия 'в уме', и лишь потом вывел результат на экран. Как исправить?

Comment: этому коду место [там](http://govnokod.ru/), а не здесь

Comment: @Spectre, ай молодца!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Однозначно setTimeout надо использовать..

```
function pulse(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.top = '3%';
    document.getElementById(id).style.left = '16%';
    document.getElementById(id).style.width = '68%';        
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById(id).style.top = '9%';
        document.getElementById(id).style.left = '22%';
        document.getElementById(id).style.width = '56%';            
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById(id).style.top = '7%';
            document.getElementById(id).style.left = '20%';
            document.getElementById(id).style.width = '60%';
        }, 2000);
    }, 2000);
}​
```

Вот как-то примерно так..

Comment: И вы туда же...

Comment: Я просто ответил на вопрос..

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, или вам нужно пользоваться не `pause(500)`, а [этой функцией](http://javascript.ru/setTimeout)?